# sorting my arraylist of objects issues

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, queue

I have a Schedule Class in which I have

```
ArrayList<Processes> processes = new ArrayList<Process>();
```

in this class i parse an input file, get 3 values and create an object array.

```
Process object = new Process(processName, arrival, burst);    
processes.add(object);
```

my objective is to sort the array list by "arrival" time. so then i can add the items to a linkedlist queue. I am having tremendous difficulty sorting it, ive tried comparator to no avail.  I have a Process Class where i have my getName, getArrival, getBurst methods. as well as :

```
Comparator<Process> p = new Comparator<Process>(){

        public int compare(Process p1, Process p2){
            return(p1.getArrival() - p2.getArrival());

        }
    };
```

[image: IMAGE1]

```
for(int i = 0; i<30; i++  ){
    if(arrival == i )
        System.out.println("Time " + i + ": " + "P"+ id + " " + description);
    if(selected = i )
        System.out.println("Time " + i + ": " + "P"+ id + " " + description);
    if(finished = i )
        System.out.println("Time " + i + ": " + "P"+ id + " " + description);


}
```

Comment: Where do you call sort? Also dont use `a-b` better use `Long.compare(Long)` method.

Comment: So you are trying to sort using `Collections.sort()`?

Comment: @Kartic yes i am intending to use Collections.sort(processes, object.p). and i am calling that sort in the Scheduling class right after processes.add(object)

Comment: In anykind of sorting objects in **Java** (and C# : **IComparable**), the class of the objects you are using should implement **Comparable** so that you can sort them easily using **compareTo(Object o)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your `Process` class is something like:

```
class Process implements Comparable<Process> {

    private String processName;
    private Date arrival;

    public Process(String processName, Date arrival) {
        this.processName = processName;
        this.arrival = arrival;
    }

    public String getProcessName() {
        return processName;
    }
    public Date getArrival() {
        return arrival;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Process p) {
        return this.getArrival().compareTo(p.getArrival());
    }
}
```

Now, if you try something like below, it should work. If not please let us know the exact issue.

```
Process p1 = new Process("P1", new Date(11111111113L));
Process p2 = new Process("P2", new Date(11111111111L));
Process p3 = new Process("P3", new Date(11111111112L));

ArrayList<Process> processes = new ArrayList<Process>();
processes.add(p1);
processes.add(p2);
processes.add(p3);

Collections.sort(processes);
```

**[Update]**

To convert the ArrayList into Queue, you can try:

```
Queue<Process> queue = new LinkedList<Process>(processes);
```

Comment: thank you so much. it works. Can you please help me now on being putting this "processes" into a queue in the form of Queue<Process> = new LinkedList<Process> please

Comment: hey man i have continued on working on the code and i ran into another problem. figured to ask you since you helped me a lot before. i need to produce an output like the one i show in the picture. I should be using the queue to obtain the processes since now they are sorted by arrival time. I provided a prototype code of how maybe i should go about doing this, but im not sure if its correct. if you can give some insight that would be great! (see edit)

Comment: If it's giving the desired output, then it's okay. I would probably go for if-else if-else if or if-else if-else rather than if-if-if to avoid unnecessary checking.

Answer (score 0):

Implement Comparable interface to Process.

```
public class Process implements Comparable<Process> {
Process(processName, arrival, burst)
{constructor}

It implements the method

@Override
public int compareTo(Process p1,Process p2) {
    //write code here for compare name
    }}
```

In main:

```
ArrayList<Processes> processes = new    ArrayList<Process>();

//Add objects

processes.add(object);  

Collections.sort(Processes);
```